# How to calculate length needed for heating element (2mm Nickeline/Nichrome wire) to a specified power?

Tags: power, wire, three-phase, heater, calculation

to start off, i dont really understand about electrical engineering. im a mechanical engineering student tasked to continue the project. i dont really understand electrical stuff beside the very basic stuff.

the data we have:

- wire resistance (Rn): 0.85 ohm/m
- voltage: 220 volt (actually 3 phase but i've been told that we'd use each phase separately, so i think its 220 v, but still not too sure about it)
- specified power output: 7000 watt

these are what i've calculated, but still not sure if there's anything wrong in it:

- Current = P/V = 7000/220 = 31.8 ampere
- Resistance required = P/I^2 = 7000/31.8^2 = 6.91 ohm
- Required length = R/Rn = 6.91/0.85 = 8.13 meter

the thing is, previous project uses up to 75 meters. a lot more that what my calculation shows, which is 8.13 meters.

so, did i calculate it wrong? if so, how do i properly calculate this?

did i calculate it wrong by calculating current based on required power output? shouldnt it be power input from power line which i still have no data yet, beside voltage and it being 3 phase?

another data i forgot to add:

- the target temperature is around 1000°C
- power input: 3 phase, 10 A, 220 V, 6600VA

thanks in advance

[image: power input]

Comment: What  are you heating up? Must it be NiCr wire? or can you a quartz heater or tungsten heater with forced air? Or is this just homework? Variables include hotspot temp max, thermal conductance/resistance, radiant and conducted heat transfer and temperature gradients

Comment: its for electric furnace for heating metal that is going to be tested (for metallurgy class). idk what the wire name's is in english, tried to google it but result seems to be inconclusive. its called "Nikelin" here. [here's a picture of it](https://images.tokopedia.net/img/cache/700/product-1/2018/11/29/14177570/14177570_652fc617-c676-4289-b5ea-0d02b8106485_593_600.jpeg)

Comment: btw, id be glad if you can help me more for that stuff you mentioned. resistance is assumed to be constant so far. 

> Variables include hotspot temp max, thermal conductance/resistance, radiant and conducted heat transfer and temperature gradients

Comment: I'll do. Its about 1000 degree Celsius. I didnt mention it cause it only mentioned by my prof in passing while telling me to read the paper published by previous student. and due to covid situation, their paper is a lot less than ideal.

Comment: they keep mentioning about capacity of 7000 watt, which i thought that the specified output.

Comment: **The resistance rises with termperature thus power is reduced. It can be used in parallel  to lower resistance but must not exceed working temperature of wire with suitable insulation and PID temperature control.**  So you have insufficient info.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I see. What else I'm missing, beside wire resistance vs temperature data?

Comment: references https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Thermal_conductivity  and https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Local_thermodynamic_equilibrium  and history of heat by James Maxwell https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_Z23vxaOhW0sC/page/n25/mode/2up  Have you studied Thermodynamics yet?  https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Laws_of_thermodynamics

Comment: You may change to any language ... but your target materials, purpose are not defined in question, nor is the furnace. You need a lot more design specs on conduction, convection and radiation

Comment: Idk how to say it, but, the people tasking me with this project (my professor) didn't really answer my question in regard of that. I did ask him about whether I should calculate based on material being heated inside. The answer is basically "just calculate air temperature inside" even though it eventually will be used to heat metal. At this point I'm going to just ballpark everything with the available data.

Comment: The temperature inside depends on the thermal resistance and heat loss of the oven and resistance of the wire at that temperature and if air is circulated or not. That seems like a lame response from Prof.  Assume the material inside eventually! reaches the air temp

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 is it true that current is what limit the temperature of heat radiated by the wire like what Carloc answered?  target temp is 1000 C, but with only 10 A current running, seems like the max temperature would only be around 600 C

Comment: If the previous system worked well, your best bet would be to copy it exactly. I guess for some reason you are not able to do that?

Comment: wrong. In a vacuum with good insulation even 1 amp can melt the wire. why?

Comment: Thermodynamic equilibrium is the unique stable stationary state that is approached or eventually reached as the system interacts with its surroundings over a long time. With excess energy and ensuring wire does not exceed working temp, you can get there a  little faster. Where are the wire specs for temperature coefficient?  Even mechanical students must learn thermodynamics

Comment: @mkeith because it failed. The heating wire fallen off it's place. https://imgur.com/a/y2fsQN2. Also it have conflicting some information in the paper itself so I'm a bit confused now. It stated in the paper that previous system uses 380v 20A

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I can't find the exact specification of the wire. The only thing I see in the label is 0.85 ohm/meter. I did Google about specs of some similar heating wire, but I'm not sure if it's the right spec for the existing wire. Let's just assume the system is under normal 1 ATM pressure since it's not made to be airtight. I did learn thermodynamics, but I'm not sure how to apply it in this case. Could've done wrong step here and there without realizing it.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 since I dont have data about other heat losses too, for now I just make assumptions that the heat from wire is used purely to heat air inside

Comment: can you show a similar photo of oven?  to estimate temp. coefficient of heat loss. Is any metal magnetic?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 do you mean another photo of that oven inside (in my reply to mkeith) or random oven? I don't have other photos (but have 3d model from the paper). cant take photo either cause its already torn down now.

Comment: Use your imagination and get us the information needed to understand oven thermal properties or go for trial and error.. byt the way if it is 80:20 NiCr the tempco is only 60 ppmC/W

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 no other metal inside beside the wire, and the wire itself is not magnetic i believe. If anything, here's the drawing i made, should show the rough size of the oven. https://i.imgur.com/Vpx9Nk8.png

Comment: what are you heating up besides air and wire and oven ? nothing? ok the heater pipe is fixed and must be wound around some electrical insulation form. If it had iron material to heat up then one would use induction heat  as well from eddy currents

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 for now, nothing. but later it will be used to heat small piece of metal like steel (for metallurgy class, material properties examination). Can you show what the rough formula looked like? Maybe i'd understand more with that. Is it like this "Q from wire = Q absorbed by air + Q absorbed by oven + Q absorbed by whatever being heated inside" ? Btw, the drawing is not really accurate as of now due to a lot of changes.

Comment: For now, what im really interested is the wire length needed and whether i can reach 1000 C with it

Comment: Use your life experience with heat and cooling to remind you insulation is critical to achieving any temperature difference with any power for heating or cooling.  Your statement without knowing thermal resistance is futile.

Comment: This is kinda tiring and getting nowhere. With all due respect, what you're saying isn't really helping, sir @TonyStewartEE75 . I'm completely new at this. And you keep saying vague things I barely understand.

Comment: if you can't answer the questions to apply the 1st law of thermodynamics , I can't help you.  how much energy is lost depends on thermal resistance which determines temp rise for power applied,

Answer (score 5):

A second, probably more challenging, issue besides power sharing on the three mains phases is the maximum heating wire temperature.

You cannot dissipate any power you want per wire unit, it could overheat and eventually melt down. This is, by the way, how fuses work.

Working out the power to temperature relationship is a rather complex task involving radiation, conduction and convection in the specific boundary conditions like surrounding medium (air?), flow conditions, temperature, mounting methods and many other.

From an engineering point of view you'd better be given a number by the wire supplier assuming some kind of standard conditions.

On the other hand I love ballparking and try to toss something, given the (supposed) high temperature of the wire I'll stick on a radiation only model and neglect a few hundred K ambient temperature.

Let's take **l** meter of wire of diameter **d** and resistance per meter **R** ohm/m carrying **I** current, equilibrium is when dissipated power equals radiated one.

$$ R\,l\,I^2=\sigma T^4 A$$
Where A is the outer surface area of wire
$$ R\,l\,I^2=\sigma T^4 l \,\pi\,d $$

And hence
$$ T=\left(\frac{R\,I^2}{\sigma\,\pi\,d}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}$$

Which worked out with the initial datas

$$ T=\left(\frac{0.85\,\Omega\mathrm{/m}\times(31.8\,\mathrm{ A})^2}{56.7\,\mathrm{ nW/m^2K^4}\times\pi\times 2\,\mathrm{mm}}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}\approx 1500\,\mathrm{K}$$

rises a flag on the temperature being too high.

Anything else equal it comes out that temperature rise is proportional with the square root of current
$$ T \propto \sqrt{I} $$
so the three phase option with approximately 10 A could be reckoned to hit some 900 K.

I once more recall this is a very course estimate of **wire surface** temperature when anything **surrounding is much cooler** aiming to reckon max power per length unit.
Furnace temperature is a far cry from this.

In any case I dare say this kind of engineers ballpark always gives very good clues.

Comment: is this the rough estimates of how high the temperature will be if i used 31.8 A current? but yeah, as pointed by other comment, i did my calculation wrong and the current should be around 10 A.

Comment: @Bramble yes, and 10A reckon is already covered in my answer, approx 900K

Comment: btw, can you point out the formula if it would include conduction and convection? also, what is formula above called? i'd like to study about it more

Comment: oh, just realized its just basic radiation power formula

Comment: Just to make sure, in case you mentioned above, does the temperature will maxes out at that value for the current given? ~1500 K at 31.8 A and ~900 K at 10 A

Comment: No, that's not the temperature top value, it can go even higher if surrounding parts heat up and begin to radiate themselves. Then conduction and convection comes into play. As thought experiment think of the wire in perfectly isolated adiabatic box, temperature would diverge

Comment: so, what is exactly shown by T in that formula? wire temperature after 1 second of current flowing in ideal condition? i thought it shows the approximate highest temperature the wire can reach if the heat is radiated only.

Comment: It is steady state wire temperature while radiating against a background colder than its own temperature. It's a good starting point for reckoning actual temeperature

Comment: So, is it like, if all the radiation from the wire is perfectly absorbed by surrounding, that's the wire temperature would be?

Answer (score 4):

Actually if you are using a 3-phase system with 220v on each phase you can use 3 wires (one from each phase to common), each line dissipating only 2333.3 watts each, (for a 7000w total). Recalculate the needed wire length for a 2333.3w line. So you would need 3 wires of that length. (The total of the 3 wires seems to be about 73m, and that's fairly close to the 75m length you mentioned).

Your original calculation assumes the power is being dissipated from a single phase 220v line at over 30A. A 30A single phase supply would require bulky wiring and large receptacles, and likely be near the limits for residential use. By using a 3 phase system each phase would only need about 10A, a much more reasonable value.

Comment: yeah, using each phase separately is what ive been told to do, but im still not sure how to properly calculate it.  

so the formula would be 3P = VI for current calculation if its using 3 phase, i see

thanks for the answer, it really helps

Comment: wait a minute, i tried to lower the power but the wire seem to getting too long.

could it be that there's 2 different kind of power here? P input from power line, and P output for what i desired.


P input then used to calculate the current, and P output would be used to calculate the resistance (and wire length) required.

Comment: Just determine the wire length needed for one phase, (which will be 1/3 the total required power). So using 3 wires (one on each phase) results in the total system of 3x the single phase power.

Comment: no, wait, the current should be already specified from power line, shouldnt it?

then id just calculate the Resistance required with R = P/I^2, right?

Comment: did i calculate it wrong by calculating current based on required power output? shouldnt it be power input from power line which i still have no data yet, beside voltage 220v and it being 3 phase?

Comment: Your initial calculations (at top) are correct except that you should have divided the power value by 3, (because each phase will create 1/3 the total system power).

Comment: You might also need to check the temperature effects of the wire. Most materials increase in resistance when heated.  There might be a compensating value in the specifications that gives the resistance at a specified wire temperature. You may need to adjust the wire length a bit to make up for that.